Best pretrained model for low frequency features of images
I want to extract the low-frequency features of the image. I want to use the pre-trained models such as vgg16, resnet 50 etc. I have used them but the I am not getting the exactly the low frequency features. Is there any pre-trained model which extracts the low-frequency features of the image?
